# completely remove rows that contain ID associate with more than one industry

Tags: python, sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've seen a lot of post on removing duplicates but those don't apply to my case.
The idea is I only care about whether the dataset contain IDs associate with more than one industries, if an ID has more than one industry, completely remove that ID and rows associate with it from the dataset. Can this be done with SQL? Python?

For example:

```
    ID    |    Date    |   Industry   |
  S000123 |  oct/1/22  |     Media    |
  S000123 |  oct/1/22  |    Education |
  S000456 |  oct/4/22  |     Auto     |
  S000789 |  oct/4/22  |    Beverage  |
```

becomes

```
     ID   |    Date    |   Industry   |
  S000456 |  oct/4/22  |     Auto     |
  S000789 |  oct/4/22  |    Beverage  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select only the rows you are looking for:

```
select *
from data
where ID in (
    select ID 
    from data 
    group by ID
    having count(distinct Industry) <= 1
)
```

The inner query selects only IDs with one or fewer (in case of a NULL Industry) different values for Industry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
delete from t
where id in (
  select id from t group by id having count(distinct industry) > 1
)
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/foSYrTBV).

Comment: does it work in a cte setting? I'm using snowflake and looks like delete from cte will not work.. Do you know if this can be done with Python?

Comment: If you are using a noSQL engine like snowflake, you need to clearly specify it.